# OpenCart - Sensible workflow, database migration?

Tags: database, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm working on an OpenCart project. (Note: this is my first time dealing with it.)

I want to somehow implement my usual workflow of:

- working on localhost, experimenting, etc,
- deploying the changes to the production server (sometimes to a staging server before that),
- adding the database changes.

Now, how should I achieve this?

What I already did with GIT is I created an automated deployment flow, which consists of the following:

- building a deployment version (Checking out master/HEAD's upload/ directory, and removing the upload/install directory.),
- copy the upload/ dir's contents to the target server.

This work fine, but won't solve the database migration issue.
I think it's not even as simple as updating certain tables in the target server's database from my local database, since for example: the "settings" table contains data that's specific to the environment.
So I can't just overwrite the settings table with my local version.

It seems to me, that the easiest - and ugliest - solution would be to develop on the prod server in parallel to the localhost changes. So for example: If I install a module, which causes changes in the database, then I would need to replicate every step I took in the local environment installing and placing that module. Same goes for every admin setup I take. (Meta changes, etc.)

This sounds awfully painful to me, so I hope there's a better solution out there other than doing every database-related change twice...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While this may bring in more or less opinion based answers, it's fine for this kind of question. I understand the *DB changes* differently as you do (probably). Under *DB changes* I understand `ALTER TABLE abc ADD COLUMN ...` or `CREATE TABLE cba ...` etc. Those when applied on local system can be always put into separate `.sql` file and then executed at once on the live system after the deployment. Changes in DB done through administration (i.e. changes in data in existing tables) shouldn't be the scope of *DB changes*. Unless you manually inserted 100 products - then a DB dump is better.

Comment: First, thanks for the quick answer! I'll try to describe my problems exactly. Altering and creating tables can be used of course, but when working in the admin, for example: adding meta title and description to the site, I have to create manually the update sqls. This of course means, that I have to check the local database for changes, whenever I do anything in the admin. Simply dumping the database would mean possibly losing live data on the prod server. It get's even trickier when I install modules I think.

Comment: IMHO you are trying to find a sledge hammer tool (workflow) to hit a nail... First I do not understand why you cannot add that meta tag/information directly on live server. Your development setup does not need to have the same valid data as live server. Installing a module is another chapter - while testing the functionality on development system the data may not correspond with the requirements for live one. Then after installing on live just use the correct data. Maybe I'm just not getting your point but I think you are overthinking something here...

Comment: I'm not overthinking, I'm just used to a more polished wokflow, where I don't have to work on a live server, but instead I can deploy a new version to a given target server when needed. As far as I can tell though OC was not really designed with that kind of use in mind. (Which is not necessarily a problem for most, but it is a bit of a headache for me.) A normal (For me.) workflow should look like this: 1) develop and test on localhost, 2) deploy on a staging server so that the client can check it out, and further test the app, 3) deploy to the production server.

Comment: Of course this deployment process should not touch db data generated by users.

Comment: You always can do that, maintain this *normal/standard* workflow. But this is no more *normal/standard* for DB data (except some configurations maybe). Configurations (modules, payment/shipping methods, settings, etc.) have to be applied manually. Unless you have some DB logging, log each executed query so that you can simply copy over the relevant ones and apply them on other environments... HAWK.

Comment: I think if I just knew what the configuration tables/fields are, that would already solve my problem. Then I could write a short script, that would extract those values from my local database, and I could simply import them on the staging / production databases. I would still have to install new modules manually though, but that's easy enough not to bother me too much.

Comment: Then all u need I guess is the table `setting`. There are all the store settings, module settings, payment and shipping settings. You can distinguish between them by `group` column.

Comment: I'll check that out the next week. Thanks for the effort, I'll come back to accept an answer of yours if everything works out, you deserve the credit. :)

Comment: Hey @ZeeCoder, Did you figure out a way to do this ?
I have an added issue of having more than one developer working on the OC project..

Comment: @EyadAlama
No, I have not.
As far as I can tell, you should just stay away from OpenCart if you want to have a sensible workflow. (I'm thinking of trying out Magento for the next similar project.)

OpenCart expects a workflow that:
 1) You develop on your local machine,
 2) You upload your project,
 3) Then you make changes in production.

I did manage to automate a little (Deployment of static parts of the site for example.), but I couldn't figure out any real solution for the database.